# How do I implement timeseries rollups in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to use Kafka to distribute high-frequency financial market prices within a firm. The data comes in at rate of 2000-3000 numbers per second from various providers. The consumers are interested in the latest point, because that is the most recent price, however, they are often also interested in obtaining the *history* of the price.

Now a high-liquidity series like the usd/euro exchange rate (EURUSD) may be responsible for up to 100 messages per second. When the consumers want the historic data, they want a *sampled* series, not the whole message log because that would be enormous. They might for example only want the price history for every 5 minutes going back say, 10 days, ie, only every 30000th message in the log (100 * 60 * 5) out of the past 86 million ticks (10days * 24 hours * 3600 seconds * 100/second = 86.4 million messages in the log).

Parsing the entire 10 days of log for only every 30000th one, would surely be a super expensive operation. Obviously I could have a consumer which does this and then republishes into another topic every 5 minutes, but then I'd now have two different topics for the same ticker (EURUSD) which introduces kind of "batch vs live" architecture again. Moreover, I don't want to run out of space so fast. Storing 100 ticks per second is far too much. At the same time, I also want the very latest price to be available without running two topics.

How can this be solved? Ideally I'd like live prices at all times being published, but also, when going back in the log, only getting every 5 minutes or so of historic messages. Is this doable/feasible, without expensive scans? Can Kafka push out messages that are NOT stored in the log (ie messages that it is not a big deal to lose), but store one of these every 5 minutes, say? How would this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [offsetsForTime](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#offsetsForTimes(java.util.Map)) to get a map of offsets for required partitions and seek from there. To my knowledge, this is made possible by the introduction of  a time based index (see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-33+-+Add+a+time+based+log+index#KIP-33-Addatimebasedlogindex-Enforcetimebasedlogretention) -- so I assume it is efficient to the extent possible.

You cannot tell Kafka to store selectively based on timestamp though. You should reproduce to a new topic if you were to have a topic with just those selected messages